# Starting IText inline editing scrolls to top of the page - Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fabricjs

First of all i like to thanks to fabric team for his wonderful work.

We are facing one critical issues in fabric.js. We can't able to edit text in inline. While we try to editing the page scrolls to top. We haven't move our site into live for this one issue.Please anyone tell me to how to overcome this issues.

Reference : [Click here](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html)  @kangax have you seen this ?

Please edit any one of the sample text in the bottom or center of the page.

Thanks in advance. Please do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally We got the answer. So Please neglect this question.

Please Check the below link for more information.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1800#issuecomment-61369196